# How to Connect Django running in GCP App Engine to an external Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I have a Django App running in GCP App Engine, it has his own database in Cloud SQL.I need to connect to an external Microsoft Mysql Server that i have in a private server with static public IP Address for consult some data that i need.

How can i do it?

How can i know the public address of my django App Engine GCP to give access from my private Microsoft SQL Server? Is it possible?

I tried doing some research, but I have only found, the solution to the reverse problem. To connect from external app to Cloud SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not have a public or static IP for any app. This is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb#static-ip):

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the same App Engine application. DNS might return different IP addresses to access App Engine over time or from different network locations.

In the same doc it is mentioned how to get all the range of IPs for App Engine. Also those IPs can change anytime.

```
#Run
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8

#For every block obtained run
nslookup -q=TXT netblock-name 8.8.8.8
```

In case you're using App Engine Flex and you think you can add the public IP of the VMs, those also can change when you make a new deployment or because the scaling that can shutdown all the VMs and you will not have control on the public IPs